# Latex Beamer: HTML Tags rendered as punctuation

Tags: beamer, html

Preparing a presentation, text that involves HTML tags gets rendered as Spanish question mark and exclamation mark.

I am not particularly familiar with Latex Beamer and I could not figure out where this behavior comes from. Below is a minimum example.

When compiling in Overleaf, what I get on the slide is: ¡p¿ ¡br¿

What can I do about it?

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, block=fill]{metropolis}
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

% Define a custom footer
\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\inserttitle \quad - \quad \insertsectionhead}  %\insertshortauthor | \insertshortinstitute
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=gray}

\title{Latex Beamer Problems}
\date{May 15, 2019}
\author{Simon}

\institute{\begin{figure}[!tbp]

    \end{figure}
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Start}
\begin{frame}{HTML Tags Rendered as Spanish Punctuation}
    <p> <br>
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: remember `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, under the default OT1, some symbols may have a different meaning in text. Also, why are you adding a "floating" figure in `\institute`?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

(I usually do before `inputenc`) and it will work.

The default is OT1 in which (due to space limitations) certain chars have a different meaning in text mode.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags are no normal text, they are source code and should be rendered as such. Either with the build in verbatim stuff or `\lstinline` from the `listsings` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \verb|<p> <br>|

    \lstinline|<p> <br>|

\end{document}
```